# adjective to go with "commitment"

Tags: adjectives

Need adjective to describe commitment of older doctor who chairs a department. Using in a note of thanks, need to connote seriousness, nothing too dramatic

Comment: Steadfast . . . .

Comment: dedicated, invaluable...

Comment: Use articles in note of thanks.

Comment: Assiduous, conscientious ...

Comment: John Lawler - could you explain what you mean?